# Meaning of divergence in an integral

Tags: integration, divergence-operator

What does the statement

> "$\int (1/x) dx$ is logarithmically divergent when $x\to\infty$" mean?

Shouldn't integrand just be approaching zero?

Comment: They never said anything about the integrand. They say that the _integral_ is divergent as $x\to \infty$. What exactly are you having difficulties understanding?

Comment: It doesn't entirely make sense to say this about an indefinite integral; a more sensible statement would be something like $\int_1^x 1/y dy$ is logarithmically divergent as $x \to \infty$".

Answer (score 2):

$$\int \frac{1}{x}\ dx = \ln(x)+ C$$

Which diverges as a logarithm (which indeed is) as $x\to +\infty$.